# Implementing camera tour along 3D text in React using Three.js and GLTF model with mouse wheel scroll

Tags: reactjs, animation, three.js, gltf, 3d-model

[this the visual representation of the 3d text model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eomH7.png)

[This the drive link of the 3D model itself and the video representation of what i am actually trying to acheieve](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1de3Qe5xqzIRTajThPT7GJJMjC-PIgy23?usp=sharing)

I have a 3D model of text written "ENRAPTURE" in a glTF file, and I'm working on implementing it in a React application using Three.js. I want to create a camera tour that moves along the text of the 3D model in a specific path.

Specifically, I would like the camera to start above the letter "E" and smoothly move over it, then take a turn and move over the letter "N," and continue in the same manner for the remaining letters "R," "A," "P," "T," "U," "R," and "E."

The camera movement should be triggered by the mouse wheel scroll event, allowing users to scroll to navigate the camera along the path.

I'm seeking guidance on how to achieve this camera tour effect with smooth transitions and synchronized movement with the scroll event. Any code examples, tutorials, or explanations would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

This is the code for rendering the model and movement. I tried this approach and it is not working as expected

```
import React, { Suspense, useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";
import { Canvas, useFrame } from "@react-three/fiber";
import { PerspectiveCamera } from "@react-three/drei";
import { GLTFLoader } from "three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader";
import { useLoader } from "@react-three/fiber";

function ScrollText({ zoomLevel, textPosition }) {
  const cameraRef = useRef();
  const gltf = useLoader(GLTFLoader, "./assets/models/logo/Enrapture3D.gltf");
  const [modelLoaded, setModelLoaded] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    gltf.scene.traverse((child) => {
      if (child.isMesh) {
        child.material.depthWrite = true;
      }
    });
    setModelLoaded(true);
  }, [gltf]);

  useFrame(() => {
    if (modelLoaded) {
      const textRotationX = Math.PI / (textPosition < 4 ? textPosition : 5);
      const textRotationY = textPosition < 4 ? 0 : -0.45;
      const textScale = textPosition < 4 ? 0.11 : 0.14;
      const textPositionX = -1 + (textPosition > 4 ? 0.9 : 0);
      const textPositionY = textPosition < 4 ? 0 : (textPosition - 4) * 0.2;
      const cameraPositionZ =
        textPosition < 4 ? 3 : 3 - (textPosition - 4) * 0.1;
      const cameraPositionY = textPosition < 4 ? 0 : (textPosition - 4) * 0.25;
      console.log("TEXT Rotation X:", textRotationX);
      console.log("TEXT Rotation Y:", textRotationY);
      console.log("TEXT Scale:", textScale);
      console.log("TEXT Position Y:", textPositionY);
      console.log("CAMERA Position Z:", cameraPositionZ);
      console.log("CAMERA Position Y:", cameraPositionY);
      gltf.scene.rotation.set(textRotationX, textRotationY, 0);
      gltf.scene.scale.set(textScale, textScale, textScale);
      gltf.scene.position.set(textPositionX, textPositionY, 0);
      cameraRef.current.position.set(0, cameraPositionY, cameraPositionZ);
    }
  });

  return (
    <>
      {modelLoaded && (
        <primitive
          object={gltf.scene}
          scale={[0.13, 0.13, 0.13]}
          position={[0, 0, 0]}
          rotation={[0, 0, 0]}
        />
      )}
      <PerspectiveCamera
        makeDefault
        fov={zoomLevel}
        ref={cameraRef}
        position={[1, 0, 3]}
      />
    </>
  );
}

const TextMove = () => {
  const [zoomLevel, setZoomLevel] = useState(80);
  const [textPosition, setTextPosition] = useState(2);

  // console.log(textPosition);
  const handleScroll = (e) => {
    if (e.deltaY > 0) {
      setTextPosition(textPosition + 0.9);
    } else {
      setTextPosition(textPosition - 1 >= 2 ? textPosition - 1 : 2);
    }
  };

  return (
    <section
      id="modelSection"
      className="flex flex-col justify-center items-center"
    >
      <Suspense fallback={null}>
        <div id="myCanvas" onWheel={handleScroll} className="w-100">
          <Canvas shadows style={{ height: "90vh" }}>
            <ambientLight intensity={0.43} />
            <spotLight
              position={[10, 10, 10]}
              angle={Math.PI / 6}
              penumbra={1}
            />
            <spotLight
              position={[-5, -5, -5]}
              angle={Math.PI / 6}
              penumbra={1}
            />
            <ScrollText zoomLevel={zoomLevel} textPosition={textPosition} />
          </Canvas>
        </div>
      </Suspense>
    </section>
  );
};

export default TextMove;
```